# Date and time not submitting through POST request

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form which has a datetime picker on it. I'm trying to select a data and time and then make a POST request to then save the date and time (along with other data), that is submitted.

The datetime data is not passed through them forms though.

Here's my code:

```
           <form method="post" action="/tweet">
            <article class="media">
              <div class="media-content">
                <div class="field">
                  <p class="control">
                    <textarea class="textarea" name="tweet" id="counter" maxlength="140" placeholder="Share something new..."></textarea>
                  </p>
                </div>

                <nav class="level">
                  <div class="level-left">
                    <div class="level-item">
                        <button id="button" class="button is-primary">Tweet</button>
                        <button id="button" class="button is-primary">Promote</button>

                        <div class="demo-section k-content">
                            <h4>Schedule for...</h4>
                            <input id="datetimepicker" title="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
```

And my script looks like this:

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element
                $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
                    value: new Date(),
                    dateInput: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

This is using the library found here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dateinput/index

When I submit the form the datatime object is not passed through the forms. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `name` attribute and the value corresponds to your date and time field.

```
<input id="datetimepicker" name="your-datetime-field-here" title="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" />
```

Comment: what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: updated the answer. basically you need to have that to passed it in your controller's action.